# Как можно по отдельности взять текст двух одинаковых классов BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python

Я хочу из классов text-success достать по отдельности текст, на изображении текст который нужно вывести это +54 и +4,150, как это можно исполнить кодом? Я думаю это как-то можно исполнить смотря на id, но я никак не смог разобраться[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я уже разобрался.

Comment: тогда ты сам можешь написать ответ на свой вопрос, с описанием как именно решал